# Code to loop through an array in one line in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am looping through the array `self.sisters` as below:

```
brothers_in_law = []
self.sisters&.each do |sister|
  brothers_in_law << sister.spouse (if !sister.spouse.nil?)
end
```

How can I write it in the ruby way and also in one line?

Comment: Your code is not syntactically legal. It is hard to say what a "more Ruby way" of writing it is, if it isn't even legal Ruby in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing:

```
sister = OpenStruct.new(spouse: "1")
sister1 = OpenStruct.new(spouse: "2")
sister2 = OpenStruct.new(spouse: nil)
sisters = [sister, sister1, sister2, nil]
brothers_in_law = []
brothers_in_law.concat sisters.compact&.map(&:spouse).compact unless sisters.nil?
=> ["1", "2"]
```

The `compact` calls remove the `nil` values on both sisters and their spouses, so only the spouse objects that exist are returned.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. if `brothers_in_law` array already exists then I can do this right? `brothers_in_law + sisters.compact&.map(&:spouse).compact`

Comment: Call `concat` so you don't create a multidimensional array and you can append to it multiple times: `brothers_in_law.concat sisters.compact&.map(&:spouse).compact`

Comment: Ok. Got it. One last doubt. After this line: `brothers_in_law.concat sisters.compact&.map(&:spouse).compact` in the method if I should return `brothers_in_law` then should I write `brothers_in_law` after the above line or is the above line enough to return the array?

Comment: The oneliner will be enough to return the array

Comment: @benjessop: your code too does not expect `sisters` to be nil.

Comment: `unless sisters.nil?` is better, but it may leave `brothers_in_law` is nil. The original code does not have this behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

In ruby, a rule of thumb is: if you have an `each` loop that is used for anything other than simply iterating the elements, there is 99% chance there is a better method.

```
brothers_in_law = sisters.map(&:spouse).reject(&:nil?)
# or 
brothers_in_law = sisters.map(&:spouse).compact
# or in ruby 2.7+
brothers_in_law = sisters.filter_map(&:spouse)
```

Comment: These examples intentionally ignore potential nilness of `sisters`.

Comment: Does that mean that this code will not work if `sisters` array is `nil`?

Comment: @Lax_Sam: it means that this nilness should be handled elsewhere. For example by doing `sisters ||= []` before this line.

Comment: Can't I write it like this? `brothers_in_law = self.sisters&.map(&:spouse).reject(&:nil?)`

Comment: You can, but this will leave your `brothers_in_law` as nil if `sisters` is nil. Anyhow, the matter of this nil check is orthogonal to the one-line form of your loop.